# How to check how much request called in function - Sinon jQuery ajax method

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine, sinon

I have a object with function with ajax request to server

```
saveFoodtype: function () {
     $.ajax({
            url: app.serverLink + 'foodTypes',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                console.log("test")
            }
    });
}
```

Moreover i have a test with Jasmine/Sinon

```
it("should called once put to api ", function () {

    var foodtype = new app.FoodtypeView({collection: new app.FoodtypeCollection()});
    var callbacks = sinon.spy(foodtype,"saveFoodtype");
    foodtype.saveFoodtype();

    expect(callbacks.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();

});
```

But when i paste next ajax request in this method -> **expect** is true ;
It's possible to check in test function to send only 1 request to server although 2 requests in function for example:

For code example :

```
saveFoodtype: function () {

  $.ajax({...}); //First ajax
  $.ajax({...}); //Second ajax

}
```

> 2 requests in function **saveFoodtype** - > TEST FALSE
>
> 1 request in function **saveFoodtype** - > TEST TRUE

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by `paste next ajax request`, can you add code to your second part of the question as well?

Comment: @WinterSoldier i adding code